# How to get a controller inside plugin?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I access an action controller inside controller plugin?

I need to acces it in the `preDispatch` method.

```
class My_Controller_Plugin_MyPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
  public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
  {
    $actionController = ?;
  }
}
```

Comment: i am not sure why do you want that , but there is `$request->getControllerName()` and `$request->getActionName()` and it return the current controller name and ActionName , is that enough ??

Comment: I'm with tawfekov.  Why would you want to do this?  This plugin's `preDispatch` exists before your controller has been `init()` and actionControllers aren't designed to have random instances kicking around.  Perhaps you want an action helper that can hook into your actionController's `preDispatch` ?

Comment: For example, I want to set some properties on the controller ($actionController->a = 'A', $actionController->b = 'b') without having to do it in every controller's init method.

Answer (score 3):

I know that I'm 2 years late to the party, but since I stumbled across this while looking for it myself I figured I'd post anyway.  What you're looking for is:

```
//$module = $request->getModuleName(); // Not everyone uses modules.
$controller = $request->getControllerName();
$action = $request->getActionName();
```

Caveat...  This is only giving you what was *requested*.  If you change the request after dispatch this won't be accurate anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
  {
    $actionController = $this->getActionController();
  }
```

#### Edit

Actually this won't work in plugin (will work in action helper).

Some possible workarounds:

- subclass Zend_Controller_Action
- instead accessing the controller, access the plugin from controller using plugin broker
- move plugin logic to action helper
- store the data as bootstrap param
- store the data in the Registry

Comment: Are you sure about that? This works inside an action helper - one of the few places where you can actually get access to the controller _instance_. It doesn't work inside a front-controller plugin, does it?

Comment: Actually this doesn't work. I just tried it myself :) I dis-accepted the answer (if a word like that exists).